# Building a "deck" in python

Tags: python

I've just started learning to program and am now attempting to write a blackjack program.  A problem I've come across is in my way of representing a deck, here's how I did it (the suit doesn't matter to me):

```
A = 11
J = 10
Q = 10
K = 10

deck = [A, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, J, Q, K
    ] * 4
```

The problem is when face cards are 'dealt' they show a 10 (11 for A..) when I'd like them to show as J or Q or K or A.

Here's the deal function:

```
def deal(competitor, x):
    for i in range (0,x):
        card = shoe[0] 
        dealt.append(card)
        competitor.append(card)
        shoe.remove(card)
```

Any fixes?

Comment: instead of `A=11`, insert `A='A'` in the list

Comment: You can use a dictionary which associates a key (string for example) to a value (int for example): `deck = {'A': 10, '2': 2, ...}`.

Answer (score 4):

First, the easiest way to do this sort of mapping is with a dictionary. Second, your `deck` as it stands is going to run into [a common problem with multiplying `list`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly). You can represent the deck and look up face cards with the following:

```
face_map = {'A':11, 'J':10, 'Q':10, 'K':10}
deck = list('A23456789JQK'*4)
```

With this new `deck` and `face_map`, you can look up the value of any given card with `face_map.get(card) or int(card)`, which will return the retrieved value for any face card, or the integer value of non-face cards. Here's a demo:

```
>>> print(*(face_map.get(card) or int(card) for card in 'A23456789JQK'))
11 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 10 10
```